# How can I include more fields to where condition using ransack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, meta-search, ransack

I'm building a query using ransack predicates, so that means I need a lot of conditions for a WHERE clause SQL-wise. Here's what I have as a Hash of conditions for ransanck's `search` method:

This is the console output of `params[:q]`

```
{"price_gteq"=>"0", "rooms_gteq"=>"1", "baths_gteq"=>"1", "has_photos_true"=>"0", "zone_id"=>"1", "deal_type_eq"=>"1", "s"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"price", "dir"=>"asc"}}, "price_lteq"=>"2500000", "rooms_lteq"=>"2", "baths_lteq"=>"7", "sector_id_in"=>nil}
```

And this is the SQL query it generates:

```
Property.search(params[:q]).result.to_sql
```

Which gives:

```
SELECT "properties".* FROM "properties" LEFT OUTER JOIN "sectors" ON "sectors"."id" = "properties"."sector_id" WHERE (("properties"."price" >= 0.0 AND "properties"."price" <= 2500000.0)) ORDER BY "properties"."price" ASC
```

How can I include ALL the fields inside the `where` clause?

As you can see, only the `:price` field remains inside the `where` clause. I need `:baths` and `:rooms` to be included for the `where` clause too.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my own problem fortunately, What happened was that I was using the UNRANSACKABLE_ATTRS array for my model to exclude the aforementioned fields from **sorting** (The default Sorting methodology provided by Ransack), but I didn't know this would affect **search** as well. Anyways I removed the UNRANSACKABLE_ATTRS array and every condition in search started to work as expected. :)